# How to know if two images are intersect while one image moving in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, ontouchlistener, android-gesture

In my application, i am moving image around the screen by using `onTouchListener`.

I have another two images in the same view.
My problem is that, when the moving image, touches any of the other images, i need to perform a certain action
(that means if images are intersected, then do something).

How can this be achieved?.Please help me asap

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why don't use separate touch listeners for each ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to use `Rect.intersects(Rect, Rect)`, like this example:

```
Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
myView.getHitRect(myViewRect);

Rect otherViewRect1 = new Rect();
otherView1.getHitRect(otherViewRect1);

Rect otherViewRect2 = new Rect();
otherView2.getHitRect(otherViewRect2);

if (Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect1)) {
  // Intersects otherView1
}

if (Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect2)) {
  // Intersects otherView2
}
```

Reference is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29).

Comment: @user2681425 : this is not working in my case. can you update your question with solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In onTouch with move action you can get rectangle bound of your moving images and another. Check if your moving rect intersect with another by intersect function like:
Rect movingBound = new Rect();
Rect[] anotherImagesBound = new Rect[...]

get Rect bound by:

```
Rect movingBound = new Rect();
movingImage.getHitRect(movingBound);
```

same with another imageView.
loop in the anotherImagesBound and check :

```
if (anotherImagesBound[index].intersect(movingBound)){ 
  // do something here
}
```

Note: you must update movingBound in every touch action, but your another ImageView you should get once.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

When you move your image in the onTouch listener, check for rectangle intersection between View a and View b using:

```
a.getLeft() <= b.getRight() &&
b.getLeft() <= a.getRight() &&
a.getTop() <= b.getBottom() &&
b.getTop() <= a.getBottom()
```