# Android ImageView Collision Detection?

Tags: android, imageview, collision

I'm trying to make something happen when two ImageViews intersect each other. This is the code that I used:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect();
imageView.getHitRect(rect1);
Rect rect4 = new Rect();
imageView2.getHitRect(rect4);

boolean collision = false; 
collision = rect1.intersect(rect4);
if(collision = true){
    button.setText("collided"); 
}else
    button.setText("not collided");
```

However, the boolean just changed to true when the app starts. The first ImageView stays still while the other moves towards the first one (it's not a sprite, but it moves in the direction of the first ImageView and moves past it). I want the boolean to change when the two ImageViews intersect. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
 Rect rc1 = new Rect();
 imageView1.getDrawingRect(rc1);
 Rect rc2 = new Rect();
 imageView2.getDrawingRect(rc2);
 if (Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2) {
   // intersection is detected
   // here is your method call
 }
```

Comment: Too bad your awnser is not submitted as the correct one. It helped me today. Thanks alot. I had to put this code outside my timer tick event to let it work. Not sure why. Got any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the Internet for days and this is what worked for me. Amazing.

Remember to check for collisions every second or something

[How to know if two images are intersect while one image moving in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398198/how-to-know-if-two-images-are-intersect-while-one-image-moving-in-android)